# Restricting Amazon S3 Access in AWS Amplify to Users from Specific Cognito User Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

There are similar questions around Stack overflow, none of which with good answer, and most of them outdated.

My goal is allowing any **authenticated users read** permissions to s3 amplify storage, and **write** access to Cognito users from **'admins' group**.

according to amplify [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/storage/configure-storage/#s3-access-permissions), when setting up/updating amplify s3 storage I should be prompted configuring access to 'Individual Group access':

```
? Select groups:
  ◉ EMPLOYEE

> ◉ MANAGER
```

My prompt:

```
❯ amplify update storage for 'Individual Group access'                                                                                                                                    ─╯ 
? Select from one of the below mentioned services: Content (Images, audio, video, etc.)
√ Who should have access: · Auth users only
√ What kind of access do you want for Authenticated users? · read
√ Do you want to add a Lambda Trigger for your S3 Bucket? (y/N) · no
✅ Successfully updated resource
```

as you can see, I was not prompted.

another example from the docs for cli prompting to configure storage access to specific users groups [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/user-group-management/#group-access-controls). I would also would like to avoid configuring [amplify override storage](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/storage/override/), similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70634119/10577976), unless it is completely necessary for this use case.

### Update

I've tested `amplify add storage` in a new dummy project. it correctly prompting for 'Individual Group access'.  `amplify update storage` seems to not allow re-configuring 'Individual Group access'. I would prefer updating the confutation rather than backup all my storage, removing the bucket and then adding the bucket with correct configurations and restoring the original data.

so, can I ***update*** **group access** to amplify s3 storage using the amplify cli?